# Filters for the products in home page for Wix store

Tags: velo

I'm making an online store using Wix, and I want to add a filter on home page, so the user will choose what he/she needs then click on search for example, and only the products that match what entered will appear.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, you can do this by querying the Stores/Products collection and setting filtering information in the query. Then you can display the resulting products using a repeater.

[This](https://www.wix.com/corvid/example/highest-rated-products) example is not exactly what you want, but it uses the same idea. Instead of querying based on highest rated, as in the example, you can query by whatever filter a user chooses.